# git fork - Delete file from History in all forks of my repository

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a repository in my git ( Github). Lots of people have created forks from my repository

Now, I would to remove a file from my git, so I executed the following series of commands

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch <<filename>>' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
git push --all --prune --force
```

After running above series of commands, I can see the file has been deleted from  git history

But still people who have forked it will have the file available. Is there an option as a repository owner to delete this file from the forked repo as well?

Comment: There is no way for you to edit my repositories. Especially those that I cloned locally and burned to CD-ROM. Once the file is out it's out.

Comment: @phd This should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @phd.  There is no way to edit once user forks from a git repository